# Depedency version inheritance more than one level

Tags: maven, inheritance, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

I've the following project structure A --> B --> C. I've given all dependent jars in dependencyManagement of Project A POM and version of those jars are maintained using property project.version. I was able to access the versions using property ${project.version} in B. But I'm not able to get the dependency version in Project C. Is there a way to inherit the dependency version in project C from project A?

Comment: if you have defined the reference from C to its parent project(B) properly, dependencies which are defined in the A project should be visible to C without any issue.

Comment: The issue was in my project B pom, I've defined dependencyManagement in project B also. So that is over riding the version information inherited from Project A. After removing the dependencyManagement from project B i'm able to get the versions in project C.